# Issue with redrawing ImageIcon across JPanel

Tags: java, swing

```
    protected class Racer extends JPanel implements Runnable{
        private int racePos;
        private int frameWidth = trump.getIconWidth()*20;
        private int finalRacePos = frameWidth - 2*trump.getIconWidth();
        private Random jumpRan = new Random();
        public void run() {
            while(racePos < finalRacePos){
                repaint();
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long)Math.random());
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                racePos += jumpRan.nextInt(10);
            }
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            trump.paintIcon(this, g, racePos, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, the trump icons are drawn initially on the left, but they never move. What am I doing wrong? Am I fundamentally missing something with Graphics/PaintComponent?

Comment: Do you ever run it in a thread?

Comment: Don't use a Thread or a TimeUnit. For animation you should be using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). When the Timer fires you change the location and invoke repaint().

Comment: @camickr But doesn't my while loop with the TimeUnit.sleep() do the same task?

Comment: @Soana yes, I run and start this class within a thread

Comment: The problem is that Swing components should always be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. The Timer runs on the EDT the TimeUnit doesn't. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on this topic.

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` rather then a thread, it would be so much simpler

Answer (score 0):

i take it that you use Thread class (i.e. new Thread(racer))
and the same racer instance is used in UI.
also you use thread.start() and Not thread.run() (i have seen many people do this mistake).

if the above are true: 
make sure finalRacePos > racePos. debug the run method and make sure the paint is being called multiples times with increasing X coordinate.